# Node is not in primary or recovering state

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

When I use these configurations:

```
- name: mongo:latest
      command:
        [
          "/bin/sh",
          "-c",
          "mongod --logpath /dev/null --bind_ip localhost --bind_ip_all --replSet 'rs0' && mongo --eval 'rs.initiate(); rs.status()'",
        ]
```

I get following:

```
INTERNALERROR> pymongo.errors.NotMasterError: node is not in primary or recovering state, full error: {'topologyVersion': {'processId': ObjectId('615098600402729c91e7cd5f'), 'counter': 0}, 'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'node is not in primary or recovering state', 'code': 13436, 'codeName': 'NotPrimaryOrSecondary'}
```

How can I get this work?